# How can I solve this recursive function $f(n) = f(f(n+1))$?

Tags: functions, computer-science, functional-equations, recursion

I am trying to solve this:
$$
f(n)  =
\begin{cases} n - 1,&          n > 5\\
f(f(n+1)),&     n\leqslant  5
\end{cases}
$$

What is the technical name of this kind of function ? -->   $f(f(n+1))$

A function within another function?

\begin{align}
f(1) &= f(f(1+1)) = f(f(2)) \\
f(2) &= f(f(2+1)) = f(f(3))\\
f(3) &= f(f(3+1)) = f(f(4))\\
f(4) &= f(f(4+1)) = f(f(5))\\
f(5) &= 5 - 1 = 4\\
f(6) &= 6 - 1 = 5\\
f(7) &= 7 - 1 = 6
\end{align}

I can only find the answer when $n > 5$. When $n\leqslant5$, I can only see $f(f(k))$. How to find the answers of $f(1)$, $f(2)$, $f(3)$ and $f(4)$ ? Thank you very much.

Comment: Are you sure $f(5)=5-1=4$? As for the name for a function within another, this is known as a *composite function*.

Comment: Also, what is the domain and codomain of $f$? because as it stands, the range could be $\mathbb{N}\cup\{\mathrm{strawberry}\}$ and it could be that $f(5)=\mathrm{strawberry}$

Answer (score 2):

An example will make it understand better

$ {let}$ $    n  = 5$ now $ f(n)=f(f(n=1))$

so, $f(5)=f(f(5+1))$

$=f(f(6)) = f(5)$

$f(5)=f(f(5+1))$

$=f(f(6)) = f(5)$

$f(5)=f(f(5+1))$

$=f(f(6)) = f(5)$

..............
 and it goes on so the function is not defined at 5

Now let $n=4$

so, $f(3)=f(f(3+1))$

$=f(f(4))$ now $f(4)$ will be $f(f(5))$
so, $f(3)=f(f(4))=f(f(f(5)))$

which again is not defined,

so we can say that the function is of indeterminate form for $n\leqslant5$

Comment: Unless $f$ is bijective. Then
$$\begin{align}f(n)=f\left(f(n+1)\right)\\
\implies f(k-1)=f\left(f(k)\right)\\
\implies f^{-1}(f(k-1))=f^{-1}(f\left(f(k)\right))\\
\implies f(k)=k-1\end{align}$$

Comment: This looks like a functional equation to me, it is not a function definition. So f(5) can be chosen at random

Comment: @YashMalik I thought I was going crazy when I wasn't able to solve it from context it seemed like it should be a simple problem. That's exactly what I found, thanks for confirming I'm not crazy :)

Comment: I am not sure if the answers are what I am looking for. I have been reading a book called "2000 solved problems in Discrete Mathematics". On page 107, it has a solved problem and it goes like this: Let n denote a positive integer. Suppose a function L is defined recursively as follows: <br/> L(n) = 0  if n = 1  <br/> L([n/2]) + 1  if n > 1. Find L(25). <br/> Solution is: L(25) = L(12) + 1 <br/> = [L(6)+1] + 1 = L(6) + 2<br/>=[L(3)+1]+2 =L(3)+3<br/>=[L(1)+1]+3=L(1)+4 <br/>=0+4=4 <br/> I was hoping to get a similar solution like the one I gave before. I just don't understand the f(f(n)) thing.

Comment: @Yash Malik can it be solved as a recursive function? I am thinking something like the Fibonacci Sequence.

Answer (score 0):

This is a partial answer to the first part of your question:

> What is the technical name of this kind of function?

Your function seems to be a cousin of [McCarthy 91 function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/McCarthy_91_function), originally given as an example of a function with a complex recursion pattern.

Quoting wikipedia, it is considered as a *challenge problem* for automated program verification.